# Continuous functions and sequence spaces

Tags: real-analysis

I am having trouble trying to figure where to being with this HW problem:

Consider the sequence space $l^p (1\le p \lt \infty).$
Let $ x \in l^p$ and $y \in l^p.$ Show that the function $f : [0,1] \to l^p$ defined by $$f(t) = tx + (1-t)y$$ is continuous.

I think I should begin with the definition of continuity, but I'm not sure how I would apply it using elements of sequence space.  Just a hint please because this is for HW.  Thanks.

Comment: Hint: triangle inequality. $\lVert f(t) - f(s)\rVert = \dotsc \leqslant \dotsc$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ell^p$ is a normed vector space with the norm $\Vert x \Vert_p =\left( \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i\right)^{1/p}, $ where $x$ is the sequence $x_1, x_2, \dots$. (You can think of $x$ and $y$ as vectors with an infinite number of coordinates.)

In order to check if $f$ is continuous, you need to see that for all $\varepsilon >0$ there exists some $\delta >0$ such that $\vert t_1 - t_2\vert < \delta$ implies $\Vert f(t_1)-f(t_2)\Vert_p < \varepsilon$.

@Davide Giraudo's hint shows hot to arrive at such an implication.

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but are x and y the same in $f(t_1)$ and $f(t_2)$?

Comment: Yes, they are fixed. You can consider them as fixed parameters of the function f. If you want to familiarize yourself with this kind of function, forget for a moment that x and y are sequences, but look at the function $t \mapsto ta + (1-t)b$ for some fixed real numbers $a,b$. If you think you know what this function does when $t$ moves from 0 to 1, have a look at the function $t\mapsto t\vec{v}+(1-t)\vec{w}$ for some fixed vectors $\vec{v},\vec{w} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $f(t)=y+t(x-y)$ hence for fixed $t_1$ and $t_2$, 
$$\lVert f(t_1)-f(t_2)\rVert_p\leqslant \lVert x-y\rVert_p\cdot|t_1-t_2|.$$

Comment: This proves that the function $f$ is even lipschitz-continuous. Since lipschitz continuity implies „regular“ continuity, this shows the assertion.